# Set xWorkb = New workbook not working, ActiveX error

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code below, It works like a charm but I'm curious about some things.

- Why can't I make a `Set xWorkb = new Workbook` statement? Instead I use the `Dim xWorkb as new Workbook`, which works. But I've learned (hopefully correct) that using the `new` statement within a `Dim` is bad practice, and that you should create the object seperately. So why doesn't it work? I get a ActiveX component can't create object error, but the `xWorkb` is still being created later as an object right due to the new statement in the `Dim` section? Makes me confusing.
- Why can't I use the `excel.application.workbooks` when defining variable `xApp`? Is it because I have to specify a workbook and can't just leave the workbooks empty like that? I get a type mismatch error when I'm trying to change `excel.application` to `excel.application.workbooks`.

```
Sub tester()

    Dim xWorkb As New Workbook
    Dim xApp As Excel.Application: Set xApp = New Excel.Application
    Dim xFiles_target() As Variant
    Dim file_path As String

    xFiles_target = Array("Bella.xls", "Fizz.xls", "Milo.xls", "Jake.xls")
    file_path = Dir("C:\Users\hans\Desktop\")

    Do While Len(file_path) > 0
        Debug.Print file_path
        If UBound(Filter(xFiles_target, file_path)) >= 0 Then
        Debug.Print "found " & file_path
        Set xWorkb = xApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hans\Desktop\" & file_path)
        xApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "tester"
        xWorkb.Save
        xWorkb.Close
        End If
        file_path = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why my code doesn't get intendented, I have pressed Ctrl + K but it just shifts... Can a mod please fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create new workbooks with `New` because workbooks are coupled with `Application` and must be created with `Workbooks.Add` or `Workbooks.Open`.

`Dim xWorkb as new Workbook` does not work - it appears to work because you don't access `xWorkb` between declaring it and assigning it with `Workbooks.Open`. If you did, you would get the same  ActiveX component can't create object error.
The error is because `Excel.Workbook` does not have any public constructors.

You cannot define a variable as `excel.application.workbooks` because that is not a type. It is a property named `Workbooks`, of type `Excel.Workbooks`, that belongs to an object named `Application` of type `Excel.Application`.
You can declare the variable as `Excel.Workbooks`, but you probably don't want to, because you will need to create an `Excel.Application` to use it anyway.